# Find distinct categories of all elements using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two data classes:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int OrderNo { get; set; }
}

public class Element
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    // ...
    public string PropN { get; set; }

    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Given an enumeration of `Element`-objects, I need a distinct enumeration of `Category` `Title`-strings ordered by `OrderNo`.

If I had an enumeration of `Category`-objects, this would be something like:

```
var catTitles = categories.OrderBy(cat => cat.OrderNo).Select(cat => cat.Title).Distinct();
```

But I only have a enumeration of `Element`-object, which reference their `Category`-objects ... is there a simple way to extract them via LINQ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nearly the same way, you need to select the `Category`:

```
var query = elements
    .OrderBy(el => el.Category.OrderNo)
    .Select(el => el.Category.Title)
    .Distinct();
```

If the category can be `null`:

```
var query = elements
    .OrderBy(el => el.Category == null ? int.MaxValue : el.Category.OrderNo)
    .Select(el => el.Category == null ? null : el.Category.Title)
    .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
elementList.Select(x => x.Category)
           .OrderBy(x => x.OrderNo)
           .Select(x => x.Title)
           .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var Result = categories.GroupBy(p=> p.Category).Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(d=> d.OrderNo)).ToList();
```